# Division in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Going through the python doc and doing the following operation:

```
ravi@user-ThinkCentre-M90:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 17/3
5
>>>
```

Why the output is not a float num?

Comment: `from __future__ import division` for the new behaviour, python 2 uses floor division by default

Comment: the result type will be **int** in **Python 2.7** which is you are using and the result type will be float in all **python 3.x** versions. You can read all the details in the [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). You will get the new behavior by using the future statement suggested by @Chris_Rands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `17/3.0`

It is a different place of python2 and python3.

Comment: thanks, got the diff

Answer (score 2):

try dividing it this way:

```
17/3.0
```